# Android PUSH notifications with PendingIntent overriding previous

Tags: android

I have an application that receive PUSH notifications. When notification "not1" is received, it shows as usual using notification manager. But when "not2" is received, is not showing below "not1" but overriding it. I need show all notifications.

I thought that using different requestCode for PendingIntent will solve the problem, but not. I also tried with PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag and many others (including no flags). My code right now is like this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;
Notification notification = null;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("text", text);
notificationIntent.putExtra("url", url);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder = setBuilderNormalNotification(builder, context, text, intent);
notification = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(builder).bigText(text).build();
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Where function setBuilderNormalNotification is the next:

```
private static NotificationCompat.Builder setBuilderNormalNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder builder, Context context, String text, PendingIntent intent)
{
    builder
    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), getNotificationIcon()))
    .setContentText(text)
    .setContentIntent(intent)
    .setWhen(0)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND  | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
    .setAutoCancel(true);

    return builder;
}
```

What Am I doing wrong, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [NotificationManager.notify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `notificationManager.notify(0, notification);` That 0 is the constant ID you are using, since it is always the same the notifications stack.